# Does space complexity change if moving items from one data structure to another without adding new objects?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

I have the following function, that checks for the first duplicate value in an array.
Example: an array input of `[123344]` would return `3`.

I believe the space complexity is O(1) since the total space being used remains constant. Is this correct?

```
#o(n) time.
#o(1) space or o(n) space?
def firstDuplicateValue(array):
    found = set()
    while len(array) > 0:
        x = array.pop(0) #we remove elements from the array as we add them to the set
        if x in found:
            return x
        else:
            found.add(x)
    return -1
```

Comment: `found` grows with the number of unique values seen. Hardly constant.

Comment: @blhsing yes, but array shrinks simultaneously.

Comment: True. Did not notice that part. *O(1)* indeed space-wise then. Time-wise, it's *O(n ^ 2)* overall since `array.pop(0)` costs *O(n)* itself.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know pop was such an expensive function. if the array were reversed, pop without an index would change this?

Comment: That's correct. Or you can use [`deque.popleft`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.popleft) instead.

Comment: Not sure why you have to do *pop* - if you have *found* as *set* already?  Just loop and check, 2nd time seen the same *num* that's the answer.

Comment: @DanielHao the point is to reduce the space complexity of the algorithm to O(1) instead of O(n)

Comment: Theoretically, a space complexity of O(1) is unheard of! Iterating on an array of n elements requires a counter of log(n) bits, so it is unreasonable to hope for better than O(log(n)) space complexity in theory.

Comment: @Stef O(1) is a simplification of the actual space being used purely for development of efficient algorithms. (Big O Notation) A space complexity of O(1) means the space is constant, and doesn't grow with the input size.

Comment: Your comment in the code says `#o(n) time.` but that's not correct for two reasons. First, don't confuse o() and O(), which are very different. Second, this function is O(n^2), not O(n). This is because of the repeated use of `array.pop(0)`. As a good rule of thumb: never use `.pop(0)` in python. Use `.pop()` if you can, or find some other way. `.pop(0)` is terribly inefficient, as it removes the first element, then moves every other element one space up to fill the gap.

Comment: Ah, the sample input made me think it's the first consecutive duplicate. If you're concerned about space, my first thought in python would be to accept an iterable as the function argument. If your goal is to work in-place, with no extra space usage, then I would use the input array to store your data (which obviously hurts time complexity)

Answer (score 0):

### Space complexity

I have to answer "no, the space complexity is not O(1)" for two reasons. The first is theoretical and pedantic, the second is more practical.

We typically consider space complexity to be the extra space which your program needs access to in addition to the input it is given.

Some programs read the input but are not allowed to modify it. For these programs, your question isn't raised and the space complexity is exactly the space taken by all the extra variables and data structures created in the program.

Some programs are explicitly allowed to modify the input. Still, for those programs, the space complexity only counts the extra space, not the space already in the input. For these programs it is quite possible to have a space complexity of O(log(n)). A space complexity of O(1) is unheard of in theory, because to iterate over an input consisting in an array of n elements, you need a counter variable that can count up to n, which requires log(n) bits. So, when people say O(1) in practice, they probably mean O(log(n)) in theory. This is my first reason to answer no: if we're being pedantic, the space complexity cannot be better than O(log(n)) in theory.

Your program modifies the input `array` by deleting elements from it, and stores these elements in an extra data structure `found`. In theory, this new data structure could fit exactly in the space liberated from the input array, and if that were the case, you would be right that the complexity of your algorithm is better than O(n). In practice, it looks shady because:

- there is no disclaimer in your function that warns the user that it might destroy the input;
- there is no guarantee by the python interpreter that `array.pop()` will really free space on the computer.

In practice, python interpreters typically only resize the array when it doubles or halves ido not free space when using `array.pop()`, until you've popped about half the values in the array. This is my second reason to say no: you need to pop at least n/2 values from the input array before any space will be freed. Before that happens, you will have used n/2 space in your extra data structure `found`. Hence the space complexity of your function will not be better than O(n) with a standard python interpreter.

### Time complexity

Your fist comment in the code says `#o(n) time.`. But that is not correct for two reasons. First, don't confuse **o()** and **O()**, which are very different. Second, this function is O(n^2), not O(n). This is because of the repeated use of `array.pop(0)`. As a good rule of thumb: never use `list.pop(0)` in python. Use `list.pop()` if you can, or find some other way.

`list.pop(0)` is terribly inefficient, as it removes the first element, then moves every other element one space up to fill the gap. Thus, every call to `list.pop(0)` has O(n) time complexity, and your function makes up to n calls to `list.pop(0)`, so the function has O(n^2) time complexity.